# SQL query based on dropdown selection

Tags: php, mysql, database, date

I want to write an SQL query based on dropdown selection values.

For example, if admin selects today, then SQL query should get only today's records and so on.

**HTML**

```
<select name="report_date">
    <option value="Today">Today</option>
    <option value="Yesterday">Yesterday</option>
    <option value="Last7Days">Last 7 Days</option>
    <option value="This Week">This Week</option>
    <option value="LastWeek">Last Week</option>
    <option value="ThisMonth">This Month</option>
    <option value="LastMonth">Last Month</option>
    <option value="ThisYear">This Year</option>
    <option value="LastYear">Last Year</option>
    <option value="AllTime">All Time</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="product_name"/>
```

**PHP**

```
$fixedrange = $_GET['report_date'];
$pname= $_GET['product_name'];

if($fixedrange=="Today"){
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $fixeddate = 'OR o.`custom_date`='. $today;
}
```

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM order_items AS oi
INNER JOIN orders o ON o.id=oi.`order_id`
WHERE oi.`product_name` LIKE '%$pname%' $fixeddate
  AND o.status = '1'
ORDER BY o.custom_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use concat

```
$sql = " SELECT * FROM order_items AS oi
   INNER JOIN orders o ON o.id=oi.`order_id` 
   WHERE oi.`product_name` LIKE concat('%', $pname,'%') 
   $fixeddate 
   AND o.status = '1' 
   ORDER BY o.custom_date DESC ; ";
```

or without using php date you can use  `date(o.`custom_date`) = curdate()`

```
 if($fixedrange=="Today"){
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $fixeddate = 'OR  date(o.`custom_date`) = curdate() ' ;
}

$sql = " SELECT * FROM order_items AS oi
  INNER JOIN orders o ON o.id=oi.`order_id` 
  WHERE oi.`product_name` LIKE concat('%', $pname,'%') 
  $fixeddate
  AND o.status = '1' 
  ORDER BY o.custom_date DESC ; ";
```

Comment: problem is that all records showing when click today?

Comment: which is the type of column o.`custom_date`?

Comment: `custom_date` is date column type

Comment: yes but i want it in if else if condition?  like if today o.customdate and else if yesterday o.customdate ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125204/discussion-between-farhan-dharsi-and-scaisedge).

Comment: I'm busy i can't chat

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT OrderId,DATE_ADD(date(OrderDate),INTERVAL + 30 DAY) AS OrderPayDate
 FROM Orders

 use +(plus) or - (minus) for adding future date or subtract for past date using DATE_ADD sql function
```

Comment: where column_date  = DATE_ADD(date("column_date"), INTERVAL - 30 DAY) and column_date <= DATE_ADD(date("column_date"), INTERVAL - 30 DAY);  this one is  for past 30 days reocrds

Comment: could you please write all queries thanks in advance